# The height on my soft keyboard changes when triggered multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, iphone-softkeyboard

I have an observed method that trigger when the `soft keyboard` is shown. It works fine, but for some reason the `height` of the `soft keyboard` changes after it has been hidden, then presented for the second time. I can't find a reason for this and there doesn't seem to be anything in the hide-delegate that changes its value. What causes this? I have worked around the problem by storing the height then using it the second time, but I would like to know the cause of this issue.

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    CGSize keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    CGRect visibleRect = self.view.frame;

    if (_storedKeyboardHeight.size.height == 0) {
        _storedKeyboardHeight.size.height = keyboardSize.height;
    }

    visibleRect.size.height = _storedKeyboardHeight.size.height;
    visibleRect.origin.y = self.view.height - visibleRect.size.height;

    CGRect rectOfCellInTableView = [self.loginTableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];

    //This changes the second time
    NSLog(@" %f", keyboardSize.height);
    //so I store the original value here
    NSLog(@" %@", CGRectCreateDictionaryRepresentation(_storedKeyboardHeight));

    if ((rectOfCellInTableView.origin.y + rectOfCellInTableView.size.height) > visibleRect.origin.y){
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, (rectOfCellInTableView.origin.y + rectOfCellInTableView.size.height) - visibleRect.origin.y + 50);
        [self.loginTableView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}
```

First time the height is 291, second time it's 233.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are examining the wrong frame:

```
UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey
```

When the keyboard is shown, what its frame height is at the *beginning* of the showing process is of no interest to you. What you want to know is the frame at the *end* of the showing process:

```
UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey
```

Also, it looks like you are getting notified of the wrong thing. You have not shown what notification you are registered for, but the name of your method, `keyboardWasShown`, suggests that your are getting notified when the keyboard *did* show. That's too late; this notification is almost never of any interest. You want to know when the keyboard *will* show.

Comment: Very nice, thanks a bunch for clarifying that! As for the method name I don't think it matters as it's observed with `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];` It's just bad naming ;)

Comment: Understood, as I said you didn't show what notification you were registered for, so I had to guess based on the name. :)